# Uploading Images to S3 from front end best practices

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a static React site that I am using to upload an image to s3 using an identity-pool in cognito. I did this more out of curiosity than anything.
i understand that one way to do this would be to upload my image to my server which could then upload it to s3. 
but I want to know if there are any best practices for doing this from the client side directly without a server. 
One of my concern in my current approach is that the identity pool id is public. Any feedback is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This resource [Serverless Stack](https://serverless-stack.com/) will guide you through exactly what you want to do, it has helped me configure similar "serverless" deployments.

The pattern to do what you are describing is as follows:

1. Users authenticate with the identity pool, this returns a [JWT](https://jwt.io/)
2. [Federated Identities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html) returns AWS IAM credentials for valid JWT (note: the Federated Identity must have a Policy that allows the AWS IAM credentials to access S3)
3. Using AWS IAM credentials, user client can upload image to S3

In regards to the identity pool, your identity pool-id is infact a public resource, just like your web app. Your identity pool is secured by the fact that users must exist in the identity pool and must have the correct password for that user.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to expose your id in your client codebase (you shouldn't), what I usually do is set the id as an environment variable in a `.env` file then use a package called `dotenv` to expose it to the .js file that needs the id. Then of course include the `.env` file in your .gitignore to avoid it being tracked in version control.

More info here: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

Comment: This only works for a website served from a server like node, right? I was trying to seee if my entire website could be static.

Comment: after you run `npm run build` react will generate an index.html along with its .js, .css and other static assets. You can then serve those file from any web server or environment.

Comment: but those generated files have my identity pool id in them. which i am concerned is a security issue.

Comment: It wouldn't, the `.env` file will not be bundled into distribution, you will create another `.env` file on your server with your secret id.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider similar design as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc_cognito.html

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to have your server authenticate the user request and return a pre-signed URL. This can then be used to do an upload directly to S3 using standard HTTP methods. See [Uploading Objects Using Pre-Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).

Seems like your question about public identity pool is actually a different question. I'll keep my answer to the bulk of your question, as secure authentication is a whole other topic you should probably research first on your own.